# Real time interactive whiteboard for tutoring math

Tags: secondary-education, tutoring, software, online-instruction

I have reposted this question on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/11882/2323).

I'm looking for a web app for tutoring math remotely to high school and junior high kids that ideally has the following:

Build in graphing.  The exemplar for this is the application Geogebra, which not only allows graphs, but also has a table view, sliders, and animation, and is scriptable.  Indeed, a networked multi-user large canvas version of geogebra would meet most of my requirements.

Built in drawing tools.  At a minimum:  freehand, line, polygon, text, and eraser.  Drawing tools should be vector based and not pixel based, so they can be easily moved and edited.

Editing tools:  It should be possible to change stroke, fill, fontsize, font color, location, rotation.

Additional desirable tools:  Marque select, group, layer, lock, bezier, arc, fill

Desirable Stationery:  Various kinds of lined/graph paper including graph paper with index lines (heavier lines) Polar coordinates, log, log-log etc.  This could be done as a PDF or GIF image layer, or best, would be as a fill you could position in a rectangle.

Multipage canvas.  Application should not be limited to a single screen.

Persistent sessions.  I want to come back tomorrow and see it how I (or my partner) left it.

Multiple simultaneous editing.  I should be able to edit one thing
while another user is editing elsewhere.  This may mean that the
other user may be on a different page from me.  As an adjunct, a way
of seeing what changes were made while I wasn't looking at a page
would be useful -- deleted items in pink, and new ones in green
maybe.

Handwriting recognition for math.  This one is tough.   MyScribe MathPad looks good, but it's online demo only does a single equation at a time.  webFluidMath has one approach, but it's not really ready for prime time. It took me 6 attempts to get ax^2 +bx + c = 0, and I never was able to do a 2x2 matrix.  In principle I could create the equation in one app and paste it in, but this makes editing difficult, and gets in the way of teaching the derivation of a theorm or equation.

A keyboard approach is an acceptable alternative.  The best of these I've found so far is Lyx, which has a combination of keyboard and mouse selection. MathML requires lots of extra () to be added.  FrameMaker's equation editor got one thing correct with the use of a space character to exit one level of nesting.  Lyx does this too.  I do *NOT*  want to type full TeX.

For this reason I'm not considering various TeX enabled chat room programs.

Handwriting recognition is desirable, but not required.  I will live with my scrawls if need be.

Compatible with iPad.  Apple limits script functionality on their platform.  Notability is has a decent approach on the ipad.  You can draw, you can bring in PDFs and annotate, add images, and draw on them etc.

Note that none of the applications mentioned (Geogebra, Mathpad, webFluidMath, Lyx, Notability) is collaborative software in the sense that multiple people can use it in real time, seeing the changes that the other party has made with only minor delays.

The use of 'networked' here means Internet -- The two parties will NOT be on the same LAN.  I do not care if it is application based, or web based, except that if the former, it has to run on iPad, Windows >=XP, and Mac >= 10.6 (Snow Leopard)

TeamViewer is one example of a desktop sharing app.  This is one approach, but only one user can control the mouse/keyboard at a time, and whatever app you are using is limited to the present screen.  Teamviewer is clunky to use on a network with significant latency (over 100 ms)

Definitions:

*Real Time Interactive: (RTI)*  All parties can write at the same time, on different parts of the canvas, possibly different screens, using different tools. Delay between updates measured in seconds.
*Turn Based Interactive: (TBI)*  Only one person can draw at a time.  All people see the same screen/zoom/view.  TeamViewer works like this.
*Shareable:*  One person can create a document, publish it to some form of cloud repository, then other people can edit it.  Google docs works  like this most of the time.
*Presentation* Other people have read only access, possibly in real time, possibly saved as a recorded session.

*Persistent*  A session can be stopped then later resumed even if there is a period when no one is using the document.
*Transient*  Session vanishes when creator or last client quits the application.

*Pixel based graphics (PBG)*  Tools change the color of pixels on the screen.  Generally impossible to edit.
*Vector Graphics (VG): *  Entities have individual existence, so you can move parts around after creating them, and change attributes such as line width, size, stroke color and fill.

Existing product limitations:  Most of these evaluations were done quickly, and stopped once I ran into 2-3 items not on my wish list.  Some of these may be useful for other purposes.

*iDroo*  VG, RTI, limited drawing set.  No math.  Can drag and drop images onto the canvas, or into a column on the edge, where they are stored as thumbnails. Active development.  Most usable whiteboard  of the lot.  Best for tutoring.

*VMT*  This is the virtual math team project at Drexel university.  Their Java app can run sharable whiteboard or geogebra in a tabbed interface.  Whiteboard is clunkly and somewhat limited.  GeoGebra has a HTML5 Canvas version in Beta.  Worth Watching.  Geogebra tabs can be pre-loaded with a Geogebra worksheet.  Best for instructing a class.

*Baiboard* is one collaborative app that has possibilities.  It's sketch + PDF annotate with the ability to save snapshots at any time.  This is a good example of the collaboration aspect. The drawing tools are weak.  Only available on iPad and Mac, and the Mac version is much more limited.  Persistent, RTI

*Groupboard:*  Limited VG: Objects can be moved, but not modified, RTI. Math is limited to pasting from a limited symbol set.  http://www.groupboard.com/demo/math.shtml

*Groupworld:*  This is from the same people as Groupworld.  Same problems.

*Board 800:*   Limited VG: Objects can be moved, but not modified, RTI. Limited drawing set. No math.  Multi page.

*Tutorsbox:*  VG, RTI.  Objects can be moved but not modified.  Limited tools.  Line, circle, square. Function grapher.  Has wysiwyg math editor, but it operates in a modal window, which makes deriving something tricky -- you cannot see the previous line. https://tutorsbox.com/en/ Plans start at $9/month

*Show me:* Pixel based.  No editing. P.o.S.

*iDroo:*  VG, RTI.  Limited drawing set. Pencil, line, rectangle, elipse, text. No color. No math.  Objects can be moved and rotated.  Marque select to move multiple objects.  http://www.idroo.com/

*RocketBoard* 
  This is an actual white board sharing app:  You write on a whiteboard using standard markers, and the app corrects for perspective, and adjusts contrast.  Slick way to lecture.  BUT...
* No way to import material, or graph paper.
* No way for me to annotate another person's work, or for them to copy/paste from my work except as a bit map.

*AWW A Web Whiteboard:* Pixel based, no erase except clear, 4 colors.  P.o.S.

Scribblar:  $9/month.  Free plan doesn't have many features.  Untested.

I have asked for recommendations elsewhere on StackExchange but have not received good results.

Similar posts:

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8761/is-there-a-web-application-that-allows-tandem-drawing-painting

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/89304/math-via-skype-on-a-mac

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/98874/software-recommendation-for-fast-entry-of-equations.

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/13532/tool-for-teaching-maths-online

Comment: I don't know what you'll find here, but you may also want to try SE's [software recommendation site](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I searched (unsuccessfully) for something similar about 2 years ago and came up empty.  It may be that such a product does not exist.

Comment: I would add to the wishlist:  Voice communication!  You need to be able to *talk* to one another while you work on your documents.

Comment: Blackboard Collaborate and Adobe Connect have some of these features, but they are marketed at institutions, not individuals.

Comment: @Tutor I was originally going to post on SR, and if I don't get an answer here soon, I may take it down here, and repost there.  (What is the ettiquete for that:  Put a message and link to that effect at the top, mark it closed (can I do that?))

Comment: @mweiss:  Lots of apps for voice, and most can be backgrounded for voice only.  So the app doesn't have to have voice capability.  If you are creating presentations that will be stored, then having a simultaneous voice record would be valuable, but I don't see built in voice as a requirement for the app.

Comment: @SherwoodBotsford I don't know what the etiquette for that is; ask a moderator? .....personally, I don't see anything wrong with going dropping a question in multiple places, in order to get the question to a wider range of people, but I could also hear where someone might have an issue with that.

Comment: @Tutor  Rules say only post in one SE.  Reasoning:  Having it in multiple places dilutes the answer, makes it harder for someone to find a comprehensive set of answers.  Currently the recommended practice is to ask a moderator to move it to another forum if it doesn't get an answer in a reasonable time.

Comment: @SherwoodBotsford Makes sense. Hope you find a good answer!

Comment: If you really want to have the question moved you can "flag" with reason "other" and ask for this. It is certainly a valid way to proceed. However, I think to just ask it again elsewhere while putting links in both directions is also a good option in this case. (Personally I'd go for this.) What one should not do is to psot on different sites *at the same point in time* (or almost the same).

Comment: [Twiddla](http://www.twiddla.com/1267311) has a (very) few of these features, including audio, LaTex math editor, ability to save.

Comment: See also http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/29351

Comment: Have you found a good answer yet Sherwood as I too am interested. I need to buy a new laptop first. LJM

Comment: AT present geogebra in VMT is still the best option to date, but the topic has been somewhat moribund of late.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend [Ziteboard, the realtime online whiteboard](https://ziteboard.com) for math tutors. It has really useful features for math teaching, like the [graphing calculator synced](https://ziteboard.com/online-whiteboard-features/) in real time: [image]

Answer (score 2):

Why not just share screen on your ipad via Zoom? That's how my professors do it these days. If they go into whiteboard mode, we can all write on the screens simultaneously as well and there is no lag whatsoever. I don't know the graphing capabilities of Notability but I imagine there are satisfactory apps for that.  It seems like what you really are looking for is the Zoom annotation feature.

Edit: Oops, I just realized this was asked 5 years ago. Back when there were no good options.

Comment: There is also the issue of interactivity:  a tablet does not easily provide a whiteboard with which the students can interact.

Comment: Well the key is Zoom+tablet. Zoom has a feature called "Annotations" which does allow the students to interact.  I use the Zoom inbuilt whiteboard and work with my thesis advisor this way.

Comment: Right.  The technology here is not the tablet, but the Zoom whiteboard.  Personally, I have found the Zoom whiteboard quite a pain to use, as it annotates the *screen* and not a *document*.  Something like https://ziteboard.com or https://whiteboard.fi is a better choice.  (NB:  I've used Ziteboard a little bit; I've see other use Whiteboard.fi, but I haven't used it myself.)

Comment: Sort of, I agree that it annotates the screen, although I would say it would be a very invasive feature if it actually annotated the document, no? To get around that you'd probably want to use screenshots. You do want the tablet in conjunction with it though because writing with a stylus is best. I've never tried ziteboard or whiteboard.fi myself but if they have good tablet integration then that's probably solid too

Comment: Problem 1.  This still isn't a fast math entry format.  Either you hve to use use a very cumbersome drag and drop symbols from pallets, or you have semi-legible scrawls.  Does the annotate feature allow you to draw  hexagon?  A clearly equilateral triangle, strike an arc with a compass?   Can I easily change the upper limit of an integral from 1 to pi?  Can I cut and paste the unchanging part of the solution to an equation from one line to the next line?

Comment: Yes, you can already do pretty much all of what you said with a tablet and stylus projected on zoom. I use Squid on android when I'm teaching and it works perfectly fine. Sure you can't draw a 'perfect' hexagon or a 'perfect' equilateral triangle. But...so what? If you hand-draw it, it's close enough. To act like this isn't a reasonably close solution is just being unnecessarily fastidious.  You can throw in the annotate feature to let your students also interact if you like.

Comment: You're essentially saying that your teaching style would not work with a blackboard and in-person classes.  Because this is precisely what zoom+tablet seeks to emulate(and it does more). If you can't teach these students in person with a blackboard, then I'd suspect that it's the teaching style that's the 'limiting reagent' and not so much the technology

Answer (score 1):

A short term fix that misses a lot of pieces is just a video conferencing app with a camera aimed down at a pad of paper.  This is certainly the fastest way to push equations across the internet.

Mount the camera on a cardboard 'baseball cap' on your monitor.  The camera has to be upside down to its usual orientation.  A flex lamp or spring cantilever lamp can also be used.

If you are tutoring a bunch of students, something like Google Hangouts may be in order.

As you finish pages, snap a pic with a smart phone.  Ideally this uploads immediately to a shared folder.

Later tag images to facilitate finding them again.

Use a black fine point marker.  Pen or pencil don't show up well.  You may find that using coloured paper to reduce the contrast between pen and paper will make your photos more readable.

Lots of PDF graph papers on line for quick changes.

---

Added several years later:

The gotcha with this is the image reversal.  On lots of telconference systems your local view is reversed right for left.  So a camera aimed down gives *you* mirror writing, but sends a proper image to the other end.

You need to look at your paper, not at your screen

Answer (score 0):

Consider using any screen sharing software of your flavor.  I've used RealVNC but you likely want something more feature rich.  Support for two mice or simultaneous drawing would be a bonus.  Then use it with any math drawing or presentation software you like.

Comment: Screen sharing apps fails the multiple simultaneous editing test.  It also fails persistent sessions, unless the app itself supports it.  Generally I've found screen sharing over the internet to be clunky with erratic latency.

Answer (score -2):

You have certainly added a lot of stuff, but If I was doing this remotely, I would look at Classkick. Synchronous whiteboard sharing, but full of bugs currently.

Comment: Downvoted for 2 reasons:  Recommending a buggy app is not a win. and no link to the project.