# Suggestions for Virtual Blackboard?

Tags: technology-in-education, online-instruction, software, specific-software

From time to time I need to teach mathematics to my students remotely. I would like to approximate writing on a blackboard together.

The subjects I teach are geometry and pre-calculus. So I would like something that I can easily create graphs and geometric shapes.

I have a MacBook Air M1 and the digital pen "XP-pen".

But Webex Whiteboard is not very handy for me.

I'd be interested in a whiteboard like the one they use at Khan Academy.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It seems useful to know what technology you currently have. [E.g. computer tablet for writing on, document camera, etc]

Comment: @NickC yes of course! I have a MacBook Air M1 and normally I use Webex whiteboard with XP-pen. But this Whiteboard is not very handy for me

Comment: Similar questions have come up here in the past, e.g. https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/4379/  and https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/18030/ . Do any of these help?  If not, can you please edit your question to include more details?  What kind of hardware and software are you currently using?  What kind of workflow are you trying to reproduce?  Do you want to save all of the student comments, or are they meant to be ephemeral?  What is your budget?

Comment: This one, too:  https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/18031/ .

Comment: @XanderHenderson I have edited my question. Now about the budget, I don't have any limits.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little beyond the capabilities you're looking for, but [CoCalc now has a whiteboard](https://cocalc.com/features/whiteboard) which allows embedding of [Jupyter notebook cells and timers and pens](https://doc.cocalc.com/whiteboard.html) and a lot of other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

One option is MathWhiteboard https://www.mathwhiteboard.com. It's handy. It is free.

There are quite a few videos on YouTube on how you can use it!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=el8LnfU0Wx4&list=RDCMUCMv_WF1x-BUzvZkIUc05LaQ&start_radio=1&rv=el8LnfU0Wx4&t=2733